# reading keywords from textbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to be able to read the value of the textbox and if it contains keywords such as 'cls','history','help', then it should not post/submit these values. I want to apply different logic once these keywords are typed into the textbox.

```
$(function () {
                $('#cmd').bind('keydown', function (evt) {
                    if (evt.keyCode === 13) { // enter key

            if($(this).val() == "cls"){
               $("#txtOut").val('');
            }
            else
            {
                        var cmdStr = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'exec.php',
                            dataType: 'text',
                            data: {
                                q: cmdStr
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                $('#txtOut').append(response);
                            }

                        });
                 }

                    }

                });
            });
```

Also how do i clear the contents of a textbox after posting these values.

Comment: Can you specify your problem more? What doesn't work?

Comment: can u tell what is problem in it!!

Comment: the problem is that when i type in cls, it doesnt clear contents of 'txtout'

Comment: @user , did you try changing your code as below , i think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this? - [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/Bbg7U/). (Try typing "cls" or "history" into first textbox.)

```
$(function(){
    $('#cmd').bind('keyup',function(){
        var tb = $(this);
        var out = $('#out');
        switch(tb.val())
        {
            case "cls":
                out.val('you typed CLS');
                tb.val('');
                break;
            case "history": 
                out.val('now you typed HISTORY');
                tb.val('');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

clearning the contents , you can do .val , this will make it empty

```
$("#txtoutput").val('');
```

This will make the textbox empty.

Comment: check my main post...its not working, maybe i have another error in my code

Comment: @user put a breakpoint through firebug or put an alert in this if block and check if it is getting into that or not if($(this).val() == "cls"){
               $("#txtOut").val('');
            }

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$("#txtoutput").empty();
```

to

```
$("#txtoutput").val('');
```